# How to use paginate in query in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I use this query:

```
$category = Category::whereStatus(1)->first();

    $d = $category->products()->get(['id', 'price', 'status']);
    $d = $d->where('price', '>', 0)->where('status',1)->sortByDesc('price');
    return $d->values()->paginate(16);
```

Category Model:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

But show this error:

```
BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist.
```

How to issue this query?

Comment: pagination happens in the DB, you are hardly making use of the DB in your code

Comment: `->get()` (and `values()`) returns a `Collection`, which doesn't have a `paginate()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`->get()` returns a Collection, so your second line is working off the collection. You cannot paginate a collection. Instead, merge all 3 lines into 1 query builder query:

```
$d = $category->products(); // $d is now a query builder object
// More where's. You can chain this if you want
$d = $d->where('price', '>', 0)->where('status',1)->orderByDesc('price'); 
return $d->select(['id', 'price', 'status'])->paginate(16);
```

Comment: Thanks, but show this error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::sortByDesc()`

Comment: Doht, you're right. On QueryBuilder, its `order`, Collections have `sort`. Fixing.

Comment: Thanks, But sorts wrong with orderByDesc !!!!!! It only works with the correct sortByDesc !!!!

Comment: I update question

Comment: How odd. What's the field definition of `price`? Is it `varchar` or is it `decimal`?

Comment: I use varchar in phpmyadmin

Comment: I would suggest changing it to a decimal, if you can, or cast it to a decimal when sorting, which requires a raw sort (`orderByRaw()`). Since the field is a varchar, it's sorting it like a string instead of number.

Comment: I change varchar to decimal, Thanks, I worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
$category = Category::whereStatus(1)->first();

$productsQuery = $category->products()->where('price', '>', 0)
    ->where('status', 1)->orderByDesc('price');

// Use the paginate method on the query, not on the collection
$perPage = 16;
return $productsQuery->paginate($perPage);
```

Error: Do not use paginate after get
We use the paginate method on the query builder ($productsQuery) to paginate the results. This will return a paginated set of results, which you can return from your controller.

Comment: Thanks, But sorts wrong with orderByDesc !!!!!! It only works with the correct sortByDesc !!!!

Comment: I apologize for the confusion earlier. I mixed up two built-in functions, but you can use either of them:

1- sortByDesc('price')
2- orderBy('price', 'desc')

Further adding in that in the second function, if you don't pass a second argument, it will sort by default to ascending order.